# I can't write any text into the input box, my IDE is visual studio code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

```
#include<iostream>
 
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string name;
    cout << "enter your name   : ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << name;    
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Not a C++ user, but check your code with [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_user_input.asp)

Comment: Remember that `cin >> name;` will read only up to the first space typed. So if the user entered `John Doe` the name variable will contain `John` and `Doe` will remain for the next input.

Comment: VSC is not an IDE, it is an editor

Answer (score 0):

Your error may not be in your code, but ensure you are compiling your program properly. When using visual studio code (assuming you are using the g++ compiler), go to your terminal and type in:

```
g++ yourprogramname.cpp
```

This will compile the file with g++, and will produce a file named "a.exe", or "a.out" depending on your operating system.

To run your program, type ".", and then the name of your executable:

```
.\yourprogrogramname.exe
```

This will run the program that you just created, allowing you to then input the name. If you are still having problems, try using a different terminal by clicking the dropdown menu right next to the "+" in the Visual Studio Code terminal, or running VSCode as an administrator.